# Как сделать таймер после конца, которого программа автоатически закроется

Tags: python-3.x

Хочу, чтобы моя программа по истечению 60 секунд бездействия использующегося, закрывалась автоматически

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Здравствуйте! В каком смысле вы имеете в виду 'бездействие'? Типа пользователь ничего не нажимал в программе, может быть кликал? Или может и то и другое? Сделайте [правку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1389770/edit) в вопросе и напишите доп. информацию, в следующий раз не забудьте уточнять суть вопроса!

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] программы, которая  по истечению 60 секунд бездействия должна закрыться.